# how to post javascript object to php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, rest, http-post

I am trying to post from this jquery function:

```
    postQuestion: function(callback, data){ 
        var url = 'myphp.php';
        var data = new Object();
        data.name = 'aname';

        jQuery.post(url,data,function(result){
            alert(result);
            callback(result, data);
        })
        return false;
     },         
     postQuestionCallback:function(result, data){},
}
```

myphp.php simply looks like this:

```
<?php  
echo $_POST["name"];
?>
```

When I post the data object from the jquery above I get a 404.  If I pass the name it gets to the php file, but it doesn't get the name parameter.

How do I pass over several values in the data object to the php file?

Comment: What is the value of `data`?

Comment: So after  6 years, 5 months you still don't know how to ask a question? Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and try again. Also helpful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You can pass several values by putting multiple properties in the object: `data = { name: "MyName", email: "myaddr@domain.com" }`

Comment: A 404 error means you're giving the wrong URL for the PHP script.

Comment: One way will be serializing the js object to string and deserialize it on php side

Comment: @Barmar please don't post answers in comments.. Use an answer instead..

Comment: @JoaquínO I didn't consider that an answer to why he's not able to access the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

To pass multiple values, use an object with multiple properties:

```
function(callback, data) {
    var url = "myphp.php";
    var data = { name: "aname", email: "account@domain.com" };
    $.post(url, data, function(result) {
        alert(result);
        callback(result, data);
    });
    return false;
}
```

These values will be in `$_POST['name']` and `$_POST['email']`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issue with your code. You are doing it right. Please make sure you have the valid URL. If the URL is correct then this will definitely  work. Barmar already answered how to pass multiple values to PHP end. Your approach is also correct. For passing multiple values you just add values like below:

```
var url = '/index.php';
var data = new Object();
data.name  = 'aname';
data.email = 'foo@bar.com';

jQuery.post(url, data, function(result){
    alert(result);
    callback(result, data);
})
```